# where store event handler method in WPF - MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, events

Where should I store event methods for button Click event ?Normally it's store in code behind of wpf page,

```
<Button Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
```

but in MVVM it should be store in other  view-model class and bind to click property of button like that??

```
<Button Name="myButton" Click="{Binding StaticResouces myButton_Click}">Click Me</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use commands. Your VM exposes the command and the button binds to it:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">Do It!</Button>
```

See my blog post on [delegate commands](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html) and [active aware commands](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-infrastructure-activeawarecommand.html) for the specifics on how you can implement custom commands.

Comment: Thanks for advice ;) I read Your post and also more info on the net, hope that this solve my problem :)